# I have 3 variables set to the same name and I think it only see's the last one

Tags: batch-file

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1" %%i in (my.txt) do set row=%%i
```

my.txt:

```
random    random random 
random  random words
type1    random random 
type2  random random
type3    random random random
```

What I want is a variable for the three words in the first column (type1,type2,type3).

Comment: Your sample feel completely "random" in relation to what you may be asking... If you want first token why do you have skip? Please check out help ( "for /?") and clarify what values you are getting and expecting... Note that having all values to be "random" will not help much with your debugging - consider having unique values for each token.

Comment: "echo" is your friend.  Instead of "do set row=", try "echo %i" or "echo %j" so you can see what you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "data="
FOR /f %%a IN (q28666033.txt) DO SET "data=!data! %%a
SET "data=%data:~1%"
ECHO(%data%

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28666033.txt` containing your data for my testing.

I believe we have a terminology problem. You say you want a variable for the first row, but `type1    random random` is the first row and `type1,type2,type3` is the first column.

Your `skip=` is the numbers of lines to skip, that is, ignore. The code I've posted uses the default (skip nothing, use default tokens=1)

The `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` sets `cmd` to delayedexpansion mode, where `!var!` means "the value of `var` as it changes within the loop". `%var%` within a loop means "the original value of `var`".
Since that data is accumulated with space-separators, the value after the `for` loop will contain a leading space. The `set` command following the `for` loop removes the first character.

Comment: Yes, sorry the first column is what I wanted as its own variables. This code puts the first column in a row that I can save to a .txt. With that I can use tokens=1,2,3 to get a var for each type. Also I didn't explain the skip=2 as there are 2 lines above what I wanted.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f "%%i in (my.txt) do echo %%i
```

Which is what you want

Comment: %%i is the variable of the first column but I needed a var for each word in the first column. Sorry if I didn't explain it more clearly.